# How to Split the values of a column in a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe & I want to manipulate the values in the TypeName column so that it contains only the part before the **parentheses start**

```
    DeviceName      DispName     TypeName
0   TYZ:SB_INCOMING Incoming      Incoming(TYZ:SB_INCOMING)
1   TYZ:SB_SECTION  Add Section   TYZ:SB_SECTION
2   TYZ:SB_FDR_WL   WL            Main(TYZ:SB_FDR_WL)
3   TYZ:SB_VLMCCB   MCCB          Main(TYZ:SB_VLMCCB)
4   TYZ:SB_FDR_BPS  BPS           Main(TYZ:SB_FDR_BPS)
```

I have tried this

```
doc_df.TypeName, doc2= doc_df.TypeName.str.split("(")[0]
```

What this does is it sets the same value for all the rows in the dataframe for the TypeName column. Can someone please point out the mistake

The current ouput which I am getting is

```
    DeviceName      DispName     TypeName
0   TYZ:SB_INCOMING Incoming      Incoming
1   TYZ:SB_SECTION  Add Section   Incoming
2   TYZ:SB_FDR_WL   WL            Incoming
3   TYZ:SB_VLMCCB   MCCB          Incoming
4   TYZ:SB_FDR_BPS  BPS           Incoming
```

Expected is

```
    DeviceName      DispName     TypeName
0   TYZ:SB_INCOMING Incoming      Incoming
1   TYZ:SB_SECTION  Add Section   TYZ:SB_SECTION
2   TYZ:SB_FDR_WL   WL            Main
3   TYZ:SB_VLMCCB   MCCB          Main
4   TYZ:SB_FDR_BPS  BPS           Main
```

Comment: You want `doc_df.TypeName, doc2= doc_df.TypeName.str.split("(").str[0]` what you did was to return the first entry in the array

Comment: Thanks, this works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `str[0]` for select first value of lists:

```
doc_df['TypeName'] = doc_df.TypeName.str.split("(").str[0]
print (doc_df)
        DeviceName     DispName        TypeName
0  TYZ:SB_INCOMING     Incoming        Incoming
1   TYZ:SB_SECTION  Add Section  TYZ:SB_SECTION
2    TYZ:SB_FDR_WL           WL            Main
3    TYZ:SB_VLMCCB         MCCB            Main
4   TYZ:SB_FDR_BPS          BPS            Main
```

because if omit it get first value of splitted `TypeName` column:

```
print (doc_df.TypeName.str.split("("))
0    [Incoming, TYZ:SB_INCOMING)]
1                [TYZ:SB_SECTION]
2          [Main, TYZ:SB_FDR_WL)]
3          [Main, TYZ:SB_VLMCCB)]
4         [Main, TYZ:SB_FDR_BPS)]
Name: TypeName, dtype: object

print (doc_df.TypeName.str.split("(")[0])
['Incoming', 'TYZ:SB_INCOMING)']
```